# retrieving object definition in R studio

Tags: r, variables, object, rstudio

I've been defining some variables with the "<-", like

```
elect<- copPob12$nivelaprob[copPob12$dispelect==5]
```

I can see their numerical values on the global environment,
but I want to see how I defined them, to be sure about the function I used, because they are subsets within subsets, I can find them in the "History" tab, but that takes too long,
any function that can retrieve the way I defined the variable on the console?

thanks a lot

Comment: Using history is your only option. You can `deparse(elect)` to have a code representation of the object but will not likely be the same as the code you typed to create the object/variable.

Comment: That's why we have scripts

Comment: File -> New File -> R Script You can send commands to R with Cntrl+Return.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the problem, may be you are looking for this:

```
elect <<- copPob12$nivelaprob[copPob12$dispelect==5]
```

or you can write

```
 elect <- copPob12$nivelaprob[copPob12$dispelect==5]

 assign("elect", elect , envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

here it changes environment as global so it works within function also